# Input to tensorflow in_top_k should be rank 1 or rank 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I try to experiment with in_top_k function to see what exactly this function is doing. But I found some really confusing behavior.

First I coded as follows

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

target = tf.constant(np.random.randint(2, size=30).reshape(30,-1), dtype=tf.int32, name="target")
pred = tf.constant(np.random.rand(30,1), dtype=tf.float32, name="pred")
result = tf.nn.in_top_k(pred, target, 1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    targetVal = target.eval()
    predVal = pred.eval()
    resultVal = result.eval()
```

Then it generates the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'in_top_k/InTopKV2' (op: 'InTopKV2') with input shapes: [30,1], [30,1], [].
```

Then I changed my code to

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
target = tf.constant(np.random.randint(2, size=30), dtype=tf.int32, name="target")
pred = tf.constant(np.random.rand(30,1).reshape(-1), dtype=tf.float32, name="pred")
result = tf.nn.in_top_k(pred, target, 1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    targetVal = target.eval()
    predVal = pred.eval()
    resultVal = result.eval()
```

But now the error becomes

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'in_top_k/InTopKV2' (op: 'InTopKV2') with input shapes: [30], [30], [].
```

So should the input be rank 1 or rank 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `in_top_k`, the `targets` need to be rank 1 (class indices) and the `predictions` rank 2 (scores for each class). This can be seen [from the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/in_top_k) easily.
This means that the two error messages actually complain about *different* inputs each time (targets the first time and predictions the second time), which funnily enough isn't mentioned in the messages at all... Either way, the following snippet should be more like it:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

target = tf.constant(np.random.randint(2, size=30), dtype=tf.int32, name="target")
pred = tf.constant(np.random.rand(30,1), dtype=tf.float32, name="pred")
result = tf.nn.in_top_k(pred, target, 1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    targetVal = target.eval()
    predVal = pred.eval()
    resultVal = result.eval()
```

Here, we basically combine the "best of both snippets": Predictions from the first one and targets from the second one. However, the way I understand the docs, even for binary classification we need *two* values for the predictions, one for each class. So something like

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

target = tf.constant(np.random.randint(2, size=30), dtype=tf.int32, name="target")
pred = tf.constant(np.random.rand(30,1), dtype=tf.float32, name="pred")
pred = tf.concat((1-pred, pred), axis=1)
result = tf.nn.in_top_k(pred, target, 1)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    targetVal = target.eval()
    predVal = pred.eval()
    resultVal = result.eval()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That make things much clear now!